# Installing nux for unity development

Tags: unity, development, nux

I read the article here http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/ about installing nux and unity to work on development.  I followed the steps in the Building Nux section.  I added the functions to bashrc and ran remake-autogen-project.  This ran without errors.  It also says that it installed in the script.  I then tried to build unity and it said it was missing the nux requirement of being >=nux4.0.0.  What did I do wrong not to have or install nux 4.0.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you built nux on 12.10, please exec "unity-env" in shell.

Cmake check nux by pkg-config, but nux-4.0 is installed to ~/staging,
you needs to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH by "unity-env".

If you done it, pkg-config will display new nux version.

```
$ pkg-config --modversion nux-4.0
4.0.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer.  This helped a lot.  I was on unity 12.10.